# What pick-ups are shared in co-op?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

In Borderlands The Pre-Sequel, what pick-ups are shared in co-op?

1. Ammo?
2. Moonstones?
3. Grenades?
4. Money?
5. Oz canisters?
6. Customization items?

Comment: Also could ask if the Oz canisters are shared pickups.

Comment: @Kexlox Good one, forgot about that. Added.

Comment: I imagine it's the same as BL2, so ammo (kinda), moonstones, and money are shared, grenades and customization items aren't. Oz canisters are completely new, but I would suspect they are shared. The reason this is a comment is because I haven't had a chance to test.

Comment: Money, Moonstones and some ammo ( need to confirm ) are shared.
Based on my experience, Oz canisters are not. Grenades neither

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moonstones and Money pickups are shared with all players in co-op. As for ammo, when you pick up ammo of a type you're full on, it will be transferred to another person, except for rocket ammo and grenades, which cannot be picked up if you're full on them. Everything else is per-player.